# How do I import elements into Adobe After Effects CC 2020 libraries?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have been going through many tutorials about the mighty Adobe After Effects, and as of now I have the cc 2020 update. But I would very much like to know how I import my elements into the After Effects Libraries so that I am able to apply them into my master project. without importing a project file.

Comment: I don't know much about After Effects, but it seems to be explained in [the user guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/creative-cloud-libraries.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is as simple as dragging and dropping them from either your project into the library, or from your explorer/finder into the library.

Here's more info, scroll down to the "Add assets to a Creative Cloud Library" section.

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/creative-cloud-libraries.html